Laravel Glide can't find images at urls with extension
when I remove the extension at the end, so doing this:
http://localhost:8000/img/properties/2/glvfATRS0WlUpY191EeXy0zPU60S7uJAmuZ0DK8T?w=100
I can still read the dd() of the controller:
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request, string $path)
    {
        dd($path);
     }
}

"properties/2/glvfATRS0WlUpY191EeXy0zPU60S7uJAmuZ0DK8T" //  app\Http\Controllers\ImageController.php:14 but when I put the extension back to the end, so: http://localhost:8000/img/properties/2/glvfATRS0WlUpY191EeXy0zPU60S7uJAmuZ0DK8T.jpg?w=100 I get the error: Not Found
The requested resource /img/properties/2/glvfATRS0WlUpY191EeXy0zPU60S7uJAmuZ0DK8T.jpg?w=100 was not found on this server.

I want my files to be recognized with extensions instead of having the 404 error

try removing the parameters after the extension and see if works. Also, add code tha how you;re checking if file exists

When I remove the extension, I manage to reach the controller without an extension and therefore I won't have the image
